# How to implement vague OCSP Signed Response Acceptance Requirements in section 3.2 of rfc6960

Tags: c#, validation, rfc, ocsp

I'm currently implementing an in house OCSP responder in C# and want to create a validator class for responses, but need some clarification

> 1. The certificate identified in a received response corresponds to
>    the certificate that was identified in the corresponding request;

Is the certificate in question the one the request is trying to find the status of? or one that is in the chain object of the entire request/response? what information should I be comparing between the request and response to make sure it matches?

I currently am checking if the CertificateID in the single request matches any CertificateID in the list of single responses

```
public static bool CertificateMatch(OcspSingleRequest singleRequest, OcspResponse response) => 
       response.Responses.Any(x => x.GetCertID().Equals(singleRequest.GetCertID()));
```

> 2. The signature on the response is valid

Is doing a `.Verify(IssuerCertificate)` on the basic response enough to fulfill this criteria?

> 3. The identity of the signer matches the intended recipient of the request

Is matching the responses responderID `Name` and `KeyHash` with a passed in `expectedResponderCertificate` `SubjectDN` and calculated `publicKeyHash` enough to verify this?

```
       if ((responderID.Name != expectedResponderCertificate.SubjectDN) && 
           (responderID.KeyHash != expectedResponderKeyHash))
       {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
```

> 4. The signer is currently authorized to provide a response for the certificate in question

I assume the only way to do this is to contact the CA directly, or just trust it if its not expired

thank you for any insights.